# Include js function in Angular 6 project

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular

I need to use this navbar:

https://codepen.io/StephenScaff/pen/zvaCi

```
$("a#toggle").on('click', function(e) {
$('body').toggleClass('js-open');
$('nav').toggleClass('js-open');
    e.preventDefault();
});

$(".nav-background").on('click', function() {
  $('body, nav').removeClass('js-open');
});
```

In my Angular 6 project, but i dont know where to place this jQuery code.

I've tried placing this code on 'src\assets', and call it from a script in my index.html but I'm getting this error in console:

> SCRIPT5009: '$' is not defined

Can somebody help me with that?

Comment: Are you using Angular or Jquery?

Answer (score 2):

You need to install jquery:

```
npm install jquery --save
```

in angular.json add jquery for your project scripts:

```
"scripts": [ "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js" ]
```

and import it from ts files like:

```
import * as $ from 'jquery';
```

further in file you can use jquery.
Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

The error you recieve indicates you didn't imported jQuery to your code.

You can import it by adding the code `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>` to index.html, but there is a better option.

jQuery weights a lot, and you should not add it just for this small piece of code, insted, you should use angular. Find the object with the id `toggle` and add an onclick event to toggle a variable: `(click)="navOpen = !navOpen"`. Then, add the class dynamically to `body` and `nav` using `[class.js-open]="navOpen"`. Lastly, add an onclick event on `nav-background` to remove the class: `(click)="navOpen = false"`.

Here is an example:

```
<a id="toggle" href="#" (click)="navOpen = !navOpen"><div class="menubars"></div></a>
<nav [class.js-open]="navOpen">
  <div class="nav-background" (click)="navOpen = false">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <p>Introducing...</p>
        <a href="">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <p>Who we are, what we do</p>
        <a href="#">About Us</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <p>What we think</p>
        <a href="#">The Blog</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <p>Get to know us</p>
        <a href="#">Meet Us</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <p>Let's talk</p>
        <a href="#">Join Us</a>
      </li>
    </ul>  
  </div>
</nav>
```